# How do I prove that the following relation R is an equivalence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I have the relation $R$ on $ℚ$, and $R$ is set to be the relation $R$ = {$(a,b): a - b ∈ ℤ$}. I am supposed to prove that the relation $R$ is an equivalence relation.

I know I'm supposed to prove that $R$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive in order to prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation, so first I attempted to prove that $R$ is reflexive:

---

**Reflexive Proof:**

Let $x ∈ ℚ$ be arbitrary

Since $x - x = 0$, $xRx$

Hence, $(x,x) ∈ R$

---

After attempting to prove $R$ is reflexive, I then tried to prove that it is symmetric, but I got stuck with the following:

---

**Symmetric Proof:**

Let $x,y ∈ ℚ$ be arbitrary, assume $(x,y) ∈ R$

$xRy$

... ***(This is the point where I get stuck)***

$yRx$

$(y,x) ∈ R$

---

I have yet to attempt to prove that $R$ is transitive.

I am unsure if my proof that $R$ is reflexive is correct and I do not know how complete the symmetric proof.

(Apologies if my formatting is strange. This is the first time I ask a question on this site.)

Comment: Your argument for Reflexivity is fine.  For Symmetry:  If $x-y$ is an integer, can you see that $y-x$ is also an integer?   Transitivity is no harder.

Comment: It's making more sense to me now. I wasn't sure how I could prove it, but seeing how I can show that $x$ - $y$ and $y$ - $x$ both result in integers, I see now how to prove Symmetry. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(1) $R$ is reflexive.**

Let $x∈Q$ be arbitrary

Since $x−x=0$, $xRx$

Hence, $(x,x)∈R$.

**(2) $R$ is symmetric.**

Let $x, y \in Q$ be arbitrary.

Suppose that $xRy$ or $(x, y) \in R$.

This shows that
$$
x - y = m
$$
where $m \in \mathbf{Z}$.

Hence,
$$
y - x = -m
$$
and $-m$ is also an integer.

This shows that $yRx$ or $(y, x) \in R$.

Hence, $R$ is symmetric.

**(3) $R$ is transitive.**

Let $x, y, z \in Q$ be arbitrary.

Suppose that $xRy$ and $yRz$.

That is, $(x, y) \in R$ and $(y, z) \in R$.

This shows that
$$
x - y = m, \ \ \ y - z = n
$$
where $m, n \in \mathbf{Z}$.

Adding the two equations, we get
$$
x - z = m + n
$$
and note that $m+n$ is also an integer.

This shows that $xRz$ or $(x, z) \in R$.

Hence, $R$ is also transitive.

Combining the three cases, we conclude that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: This helped me understand what I needed to do prove these kinds of problems, thank you!